# Formula Excel Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have my main sheet.

```
Account Card 
1       22
1       33
```

Same person has 2 cards. Hence, the balance is same.

Vlookup sheet has data like below.

```
Account Balance
1       5
```

When I do the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,DATA!A2:B84520,2,FALSE)
```

It returns value for first Account 1. and N/A for second.

```
Account Card Balance 
1       22   5
1       33   #N/A
```

How can I fix the formula?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to include the `$` around your data field otherwise your data field changes when you pull the formula down: `Data!$A$2:$B$84520`

Answer (score 2):

Put  $ in A$2:B$84520. Try.

Best
Anderson